# Force browser to download a HOSTS file

Tags: html, .htaccess

I am trying to force the Browser to download a HOSTS file to the users computer but it always opens the file in a new window. If i right-click the link and choose Save As the browser adds a .txt extension to it, NOT GOOD.

You can view my page here:

http://lovespec.bugs3.com/Host_File.html

I also have an .htaccess file on my server but I don't know what to put there to force the browser to download the file.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to set `Content-Disposition:`.

Comment: SLaks, what's the exact syntax to put in .htaccess?

Comment: @user2476041 refer to my answer for that information

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your `.htaccess`

```
<Directory />
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        <FilesMatch "hosts">
            ForceType application/octet-stream
            Header set Content-Disposition attachment
        </FilesMatch>
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Just a trick for the browser to think it's opening a non-text file.

Comment: Deryck, I added your code to my .htaccess but I get an internal server error.

Comment: Look in the Apache log file and find out what the actual error is.

Comment: Deryck, I don't have access to that.

Comment: If I run my Host_File.html from my computer it works fine, but once I upload it to server it adds the .html extension on the file before download, I don't get it.

Comment: What browser are you using

Comment: Deryck, I have been using Chrome.

Comment: If your server has PHP enabled, make a file called `info.php`, put this in it and let me know when it's up:  `<?php phpinfo(); ?>

Comment: While I can't say with absolute certainty this is what's causing it, I am damn sure it's not helping you.  Your server is running `SERVER_PROTOCOL HTTP/1.0`...old, deprecated, shunned, exiled, terrible protocol.  Ok it's not that bad but I'm pretty sure it's a contributing factor in this.  Find a new host lol anyone running their server at 1.0 spec doesn't know what they're doing or they have a really weird and specific use-case for it.

Comment: LOL. OK Deryck thanks and thank you all who tried helping me on this one. I'm in search of A NEW SERVER. lol

Answer (score -1):

Have you simply tried to add `<a href="your/file"></a>`? This will redirect and download it,by it self.

Let me know if that simply solution doesn't work. Working in some cases.

So here you have an showoff of my example.

[Example here !](http://test121.net63.net/)

Comment: I am not aware of just a query string changing the behaviour of browsers, so I am clueless why this would work. Could you please edit your answer explaining why that is (or when exactly this works)? If it is simply a guess: Please don't post guesses as answers.

Comment: In some cases, when you Link your file with href / src (Doesn't really matter), it gets executed. I'm not guessing that, I know it.

Comment: user3127823, you lost me. Is there an example you can point me to?

Comment: user3127823, that almost works except the browser is attaching an .html extension to the file name. If i can get it to just appear as "hosts" that would be perfect. I am still looking for solutions but they are for files that have an extension. As you may know already, the hosts file doesn't have an extension and won't work if you add an extension to it.

Comment: Your example works because it has the `download` attribute. Adding a `?` to a url doesn't change that. Either the headers have to be set correctly afaik or via the html in the document you'll need to let the browser know the url has to be downloaded, not opened.

Comment: OMG, user2476041 i got it to work i just removed that period from the file name and it works in Chrome and Firefox but not IE. This is a great help so far though thanks I just wish it worked in IE too.

Comment: Sumurai8, when you say the headers have to be set in the document are you referring to the content-disposition thing? I tried that but it doesn't seem to work though, at least not in Chrome which is the browser I tested it in.